# float absolute positined div right

Tags: css, html, position, absolute

I have the following elements:

```
<div>

<div class="top">       
</div>

<div class="content">       
</div>

</div>
```

I want both child divs to be flaot right and positioned absolute so they overlay other elements.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what you want to do, but here's an example to get you started if you want absolute positioning to the right:

http://jsfiddle.net/b2yD9/

Answer (score 1):

In both div add CSS

`right:10px; and position:absolute`